# "'StartsWith' is not a member of type 'Edm.String'?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

using EF 4.1 and I am getting an error when I try this:

```
db.Golfers.Where("it.Name.StartsWith('tiger')")
```

the error is:

```
"'StartsWith' is not a member of type 'Edm.String' in the currently loaded schemas. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 9."  string
```

what da?? the problem is that I have a string as input , how can i convert into a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ESQL you can simply use:

```
db.Golfers.Where("it.Name LIKE 'tiger%'");
```

but this will probably also work:

```
db.Golfers.Where("StartWith(it.Name, 'tiger')");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. 
It should be:

```
var result = db.Golfers.Where(it=>it.Name.StartsWith('tiger'));
```

Comment: the problem is that I have a string as input , how can i convert into a lambda expression?

Comment: @user603007,  Do you mean that `"it.Name.StartsWith('tiger')"` is your input ?